# window.addEventHandler("beforeunload"...) is not executed on window/tab close, only on refresh or navigation

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I want to save the state of a form when a user leaves the form. I am trying to do this through onbeforeunload/beforeunload events in the browser.

I have two questions/problems with this:

1.

According to MDN, the proper way to do this is to write

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => { //Handler });
```

This works when the user goes to another URL *in the same tab* or if the user refreshes the page, but not if the tab or browser window is closed.

If i do

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => { //Handler };
```

The event handler is run also on window/tab close.

As far as I can understand from the docs on MDN, the two should be equal, but the first one preferred. I cannot see why they behave differently.

2.

Event though the `window.onbeforeunload` method works, it *always* displays a dialog to the user, even if i set event.returnValue to `undefined` and don
t return anything. That should not happen as far as I can see according to the documentation. This does not happen with the `window.addEventListener` method.

The application is written i ClojureScript, and the `window.addEventListener` version looks like this:

```
(defn close-handler []
  (js/window.addEventListener
    "beforeunload"
    (fn []
      (rf/dispatch [:close-handler]))))
```

The `window.onbeforeunload` version looks like this:

```
(defn close-handler []
  (let [prev-handler js/window.onbeforeunload]
    (set! js/window.onbeforeunload
      (fn [e]
        (prev-handler)
        (rf/dispatch [:close-handler])
        (set! e.returnValue nil)
        nil))))
```

So to summarize: Can someone help me (1) understand why `onbeforeunload` and `beforeunload` work differently, and preferably how to get `beforeunload` to work on page close, and (2) why `onbeforeunload` always causes a dialog, and potentially how to avoid that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not want to show the dialog? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: We are using it to store the state of the form when the user leaves, so the information is not lost. According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) a dialog should not be shown if the function returns `null` or `undefined`. 

"When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value other than null or undefined, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload"

Comment: This is a nightmare — different browsers have different functionality, and the MDN docs can be misleading since they claim things that may not hold. For example, no browser that I tested actually showed my custom dialog, Safari on Mac will "remember" if you press "yes I want to leave this page" and won't show it again, etc etc.

Comment: FYI there is no such method `window.addEventHandler`, however I'm guessing you mean `window.addEventListener` which is referenced in your code snippets. If this is indeed by accident you should update your post accordingly.